# Popup when click on button Yii

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii

I am a beginner in yii. Is there a way to have a button that displays a modal popup instead of just a link?

here is my create button in form.php

```
<div class="form-actions" id="michael">
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'buttonType'=>'submit',
    'type'=>'primary',
    'label'=>'Create',
)); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: this link require autentication

Comment: it doesnt have a link sir. its just an example.

Comment: ok ok. You can create a button with onClick="callPopup();" and on callPopup() function calls the modal.

Comment: no sir. i dont know how to use jquery.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use Yii booster which is having modal associated with button click and lots of ui elements which will make your work easies  [yii booster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/javascript.html)